# In Flutter I have lazy loading list but want to implement search and don't want to store data on catch. Any suggestions

Tags: flutter, lazy-loading

I have lazy loading list but want to implement search and don't want to store data on catch.
The problem is don't want to fetch all data at once any alternative way in flutter.

Comment: Welcome, you might want to post some code so people can see examples of what you have tried and how it works so they can offer suggestions.

Comment: You can implement search by storing a copy of original data & then searching on it. But with this approach you can only search on data that is already loaded

Comment: The list itself isn't storing anything. Just extracting from array. And to build it, you need to hold onto original data anyway.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.